# How to change parent control from child in MVVM WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

i have a problem with WPF MVVM, i have one usercontrl loaded inside my main view.. And at my main view i have a status bar and one textbox. I want to change the text by clicking at button from usercontrol, how can i do that? I tried a lot os things here like raisedpropertiechange and nothing happens.

I have one ViewModel from MainModel and a lots of UserControls with theirs viewmodels. Each usercontrl viewmodel will have one button with need to be fired and change the text from parent Model.

Im not sure if im clear about this.

Regards

Comment: Create an event handler in the child controls, have the parent controls subscribe to those events when they instantiate the user control's viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

I would provide a command in the `BaseClass` of the `UserControl` viewmodel, which changes the text in the parent viewmodel of the `UserControls` viewmodel. The `Buttons` of the `UserControl` can bind to this command. And the title of the main view is bound to the text property.
Keep the views and controls as decoupled and 'stupid' as possible.

Then you only have to provide a reference of the main viewmodel in the other viewmodels.